# Format array output

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I get an array such as this:

```
$array = array(
    "test1" => "blah1",
    "test2" => "blah2",
);
```

converted to a string like this:

```
$string = {"test1":"blah1","test2":"blah"}
```

The array may vary in size so it will have to be dynamic.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is JSON. Use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).